# Android App could not publish photos while the apk is released

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an android app, with the function:publishing a photo to facebook via Facebook Share dialog. (My code is similar to facebook sdk's samples"[HelloFacebookSample](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/HelloFacebookSample)")

It works fine in debug mode. But if I generate the app as signed apk and test it again, it works well until I click the "*Share*". The result shows Upload failed on the Android Notification Bar.
What's wrong with my app? Is there anyway to check the message from facebook when apk is released? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set up API key correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you generate a release APK, generally you're using a different signing key, which means there will be a different key hash. You should put that key hash into your FB app settings (under the Android section).

Comment: yes, you are right, I got the "Correct" key hash after I generated the debug apk, and installed it my my test device. It's OK now. thanks.